# Animated GIF as an overlay in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif

I have an animated gif that I wanted to loop in the bottom corner of a video, unfortunately when added as an overlay in ffmpeg it does not loop and only shows the first 'frame'. Is there  a way of achieving this?

Comment: This question is related to [overlaying animated image over image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10438713/866571) may help you at some extent.

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i loop.gif -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=0:H-100" output.mp4
```

Comment: The best answers teach **WHY** they work.  Could you add a couple of sentences to explain the command?  Thanks.  [from review](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/601994)

Comment: While this snippet may address the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Two caveats: with the given option, `-ignore_loop 0` the GIF will loop as per the value embedded in it. If it's 4, then it will loop 4 times. And, the overlay filter should have `shortest=1` added, else with an infinite loop, the overlay will never terminate.

Comment: I got this error, any tips? Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.
[aac @ 0x7fb358015200] Qavg: 732.219
[aac @ 0x7fb358015200] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!